# Terraform Remote-Exec Provisioner Timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm creating a server in AWS using Terraform.

My remote-exec provisioner will not connect and execute, continually giving me the output:

```
aws_spot_instance_request.single_server_instance (remote-exec): Connecting to remote host via WinRM...
aws_spot_instance_request.single_server_instance (remote-exec):   Host: 54.219.179.241
aws_spot_instance_request.single_server_instance (remote-exec):   Port: 5985
aws_spot_instance_request.single_server_instance (remote-exec):   User: Administrator
aws_spot_instance_request.single_server_instance (remote-exec):   Password: true
aws_spot_instance_request.single_server_instance (remote-exec):   HTTPS: false
aws_spot_instance_request.single_server_instance (remote-exec):   Insecure: false
aws_spot_instance_request.single_server_instance (remote-exec):   CACert: false
```

Before failing with:

```
Error applying plan:

1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_spot_instance_request.single_server_instance: 1 error(s) occurred:

* timeout
```

My Resource is as follows:

```
resource "aws_spot_instance_request" "single_server_instance" {
  # The connection block tells our provisioner how to
  # communicate with the resource (instance)
  connection {
    type     = "winrm"
    user     = "Administrator"
    password = "${var.admin_password}"
    #insecure = true
    #port = 5985
    host = "${self.public_ip}"
    #timeout = "5m"
  }

  wait_for_fulfillment        = true
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  instance_type = "${var.aws_instance_type}"
  ami           = "${lookup(var.aws_amis, var.aws_region)}"
  spot_price    = "1.00"
  vpc_security_group_ids =  [
                              "${aws_security_group.WinRM.id}",
                              "${aws_security_group.RDP.id}"
                            ]
  key_name = "sdlweb85"

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "mkdir c:\\installs"
      #"powershell.exe Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/meno68gl3rfbtio/install.ps1?dl=0' -OutFile 'C:/installs/install.ps1'"
    ]
  }
  #provisioner "file" {
  #  source      = "scripts/"
  #  destination = "c:/install_scripts/"   
  #}

  user_data = <<EOF
              <powershell>
              # Configure a Windows host for remote management (this works for both Ansible and Chef)
              # You will want to copy this script to a location you own (e.g. s3 bucket) or paste it here
              Invoke-Expression ((New-Object System.Net.Webclient).DownloadString('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ansible/ansible/devel/examples/scripts/ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1'))
              # Set Administrator password
              $admin = [adsi]("WinNT://./administrator, user")
              $admin.psbase.invoke("SetPassword", "${var.admin_password}")
              Set-NetFirewallProfile -Profile Domain,Public,Private -Enabled False
              New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName "*.amazonaws.com" -CertStoreLocation "cert:\LocalMachine\My"
              #winrm quickconfig -quiet
              </powershell>
            EOF
}
```

Security Groups

```
resource "aws_security_group" "WinRM" {
  name        = "WinRM"

  # WinRM access from anywhere
  ingress {
    from_port   = 5985
    to_port     = 5986
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  # outbound internet access
  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "RDP" {
  name        = "RDP"

  # RDP access from anywhere
  ingress {
    from_port   = 3389
    to_port     = 3389
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  # outbound internet access
  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}
```

I cannot figure out the problem. From my local machine, I can connect to the remote server using

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName $ip -Credential ~\Administrator
```

Answer (score 1):

Winrm HTTP is disabled by default on Amazon Windows AMI. You have to run a powershell command to enable it, [ansible has a nice one to do it](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ansible/ansible/devel/examples/scripts/ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1). You can create an AMI that has winrm enabled and use that one to launch spot instances.

You can also set the provisioner in terraform to HTTPS true
https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/connection.html#https

Answer (score 1):

Note that terraform uses Go WinRM which doesn't support https at this time.

I had to stick with the following:

```
user_data = <<EOF  
<script>
  winrm quickconfig -q & winrm set winrm/config @{MaxTimeoutms="1800000"} & winrm set winrm/config/service @{AllowUnencrypted="true"} & winrm set winrm/config/service/auth @{Basic="true"}
</script>
<powershell>
  netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="WinRM in" protocol=TCP dir=in profile=any localport=5985 remoteip=any localip=any action=allow
  # Set Administrator password
  $admin = [adsi]("WinNT://./administrator, user")
  $admin.psbase.invoke("SetPassword", "${var.admin_password}")
</powershell>
EOF
```